# Can't push Git change - Change-ID not found

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm promoting a change in my Git repository from master/trunk to a test branch, "beta". I was able to commit the changes just fine, but was unable to push the changes to Gerrit for code review. When I attempt to push to the branch via:

`git push origin beta:refs/for/beta`

It fails with the following error:

```
remote: Change-Id: 987899878087967896899087e908f7098890
remote: Hint: A potential Change-Id was found, but it was not in the footer of the commit message.
```

The change ID is fine, and is right there. It was included automatically when I cherry picked the change. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the version of Git installed on your server, the "Change-ID" line has to be the very last line in your commit log.

Update your commit message using `git commit --amend`. Edit the commit log, and save it, and you're all set. Just move the line:

```
Change-Id: 987899878087967896899087e908f7098890
```

To the very last line of the commit log that is not commented out. Also, make sure there are no trailing empty new lines after this line. The commented-out lines of the commit log don't matter.

Comment: This isn't quite correct.  The change-id doesn't have to be the last line, it just has to be in the commit footer.  The footer is the last paragraph (separated by a blank line above it) and contains only name: value pairs, one per line.  Also trailing new lines are fine, `git commit` will trim them.